# Minimize the switching function from Karnaugh map

Tags: logic-gates, karnaugh-map

I need to minimize the switching function `y=f(x1,...,x5)` represented by the Karnaugh map. I wonder if I did it in the right way. Can anyone check this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simulating it? Is the output 0 when it is supposed to be 0 and 1 when it is supposed to be 1? What exactly do you mean by "the right way"? Did you do it the way your instructor told you to do it?

Comment: In case you want to cross verify fast, rely on: http://www.32x8.com/index.html

Comment: The first and the third term (blue and red) can be simplified further.

Comment: 4th column complete.

Comment: the violet can be simplified